# regexp, Extract value between parentheses

Tags: regex

example:

```
"today  [(["hi"],{"my"})],["ok"],("good")),(["gg"],["fire"])] nice game [(["1"],{"2"})],["3"],("4")),(["5"],["6"])] end."
```

->

```
[(["hi"],{"my"})],["ok"],("good")),(["gg"],["fire"])]
[(["1"],{"2"})],["3"],("4")),(["5"],["6"])]
```

[image]
In this case, there is a noise in the middle.

It doesn't work in the usual way

Please give me an idea of extracting the value between parentheses in another way

Comment: Please tag your question with the regex engine/language you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love regex, almost as much as I hate them. Writing an effective regex can take a problem from impossible to trivial.

Knowing how to iterate one is very important. Let me teach a man to fish.

Consider using an online regex tool: https://regex101.com/

Input your string:

[image of me adding in the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fnZJ.png)

Then try to Match it. I did with the following `\([^()]+\)`

That is:

1. escape the parenthesis you want to match on `\(` and `\)` because they are special symbols.
2. You know you want to match everything that isn't a parenthesis between them. So I use a no-match clause by doing `[^...]` where the elipsis are all the characters I don't want to match. I then add my parenthesis raw in there `[^()]`
3. Finally. I want to have 1 or more of those so I use `+`.

Thus I have my awnser.

[image of me matching the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du1Re.png)

edit: cannot post images because of rep

Comment: The regular expression was not properly expressed in the editor. All I want is [] brackets

Comment: Pretty common to misunderstand a question in software :-)

You're saying you want everything in between the brackets? '[]'?